# No module named 'platformdirs' при использовании jupyter-black

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Как-то поставил расширение **jupyter-black** и оно работало в моих ячейках без проблем.

Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку *Black* вылетает следующее сообщение:

**[jupyter-black]**

**Error: ModuleNotFoundError**

**No module named 'platformdirs'**

`platformdirs` у меня установлен, по крайней мере `pip show` показывает наличие его последней версии. Попытка нагуглить ошибку ни к чему не привела. Ничего связанного с **jupyter-black** не нашлось. Как можно решить эту проблему?

---

**Обновление**

После первого нажатия в дальнейшем сообщение меняется на то, что ниже, вплоть до перезапуска блокнота.

**[jupyter-black]**

**Error: AttributeError**

**module 'black' has no attribute 'FileMode'**

Answer (score 0):

Помогла полная переустановка `black` & `paltformdirs` **(не из кэша!, используйте `--no-cache-dir`)**. После перезагрузки блокнота всё заработало.